# Loss does not decrease and accuracy does not improved while using hugggingface transformers and pytorch lightning

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, pytorch-lightning

**Summary**

Loss does not decrease and accuracy/F1-score is not improving during training HuggingFace Transformer BertForSequenceClassification with Pytorch-Lightning

**package versions**

```
python==3.7
pytorch==1.11.0
pytorch-lightning == 1.7.7
transformers == 4.2.2
torchmetrics == up-to-date
```

**Issue**

Hello. previously, I trained huggingface bert model with my own trainer code. To improve code quality and implement MLOps system, I’m trying to train huggingface’s transformers Bert with pytorch lightning.

When I train BertForSequenceClassification in the transformers with PTL, however, Loss, accuracy, and even f1 score seems to not improve during a training phase. I think there are some bugs in the optimizer or back-propagation in my code, but I can’t find any problems. my question is, what is the problem with my code?

**my assumtions:**

1. configure_optimizer is not correctly configured
2. huggingface sequence classification module
3. segment_ids should not be passes during training step
4. etc.

**Tried Approaches**

replace bertforsequenceclassifier to bertmodel and add classifier

```py
self.config = BertConfig.from_pretrained('klue/bert-base')
self.model = BertModel.from_pretrained('klue/bert-base') 
classifier = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, num_classes)

def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    init_ids, attention_masks, _, label_ids = batch
    out = self.bert(init_ids, attention_masks)
    output = self.classifier(out.logits)
    loss = F.cross_entropy(output, label_ids)
    return loss
```

but it didn't worked.

### code snippet

```py
import os
import csv
import tqdm
from typing import *
import pandas as pd

import torch
from torch import nn
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torchmetrics.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler, Dataset
from transformers.modeling_outputs import SequenceClassifierOutput
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, BertTokenizer, InputExample, InputFeatures, AutoConfig, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup


def get_input_example(guid: int, text_a: str, label: str) -> Tuple[InputExample, str]:
    input_example = InputExample(
        guid=guid,
        text_a=text_a,
        text_b=None,
        label=label
    )
    return input_example, label


def add_examples(
        texts_or_text_and_labels: Union[List[str], str],
        text_index: int,
        label_index: int,
        label_dict: Dict[str, int] = None,
        remove_top: bool = False
) -> Tuple[List[InputExample], Dict[str, int]]:
    examples = list()
    labels = list()

    tmp = []
    if isinstance(texts_or_text_and_labels, str):
        with open(texts_or_text_and_labels, 'r') as f:
            if texts_or_text_and_labels.endswith('csv'):
                delimiter = ','
            elif texts_or_text_and_labels.endswith('tsv'):
                delimiter='\t'

            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar='"')
            for idx, line in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(reader)):
                if remove_top is True and idx == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    tmp.append(line)
        texts_or_text_and_labels = tmp

    for line in tqdm.tqdm(texts_or_text_and_labels):
        text_a = line[text_index]
        label = line[label_index]

        input_example, label = get_input_example(guid=line[0], text_a=text_a, label=label)
        examples.append(input_example)
        if label_dict is None:
            labels.append(label)
    if label_dict is None:
        label_dict = {i: idx for idx, i in enumerate(list(set(labels)))}
    return examples, label_dict


class BertDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, examples, tokenizer, label_dict, max_length):
        self.examples = examples
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.label_dict = label_dict
        self.max_length = max_length

    def _truncate_seq_pair(self, tokens_a, tokens_b, max_length) -> None:
        """
        Truncates a sequence pair in place to the maximum length.
        This is a simple heuristic which will always truncate the longer sequence
        one token at a time. This makes more sense than truncating an equal percent
        of tokens from each, since if one sequence is very short then each token
        that's truncated likely contains more information than a longer sequence.
        """
        while True:
            total_length = len(tokens_a) + len(tokens_b)
            if total_length <= max_length - 3:
                break
            if len(tokens_a) > len(tokens_b):
                tokens_a.pop()
            else:
                tokens_b.pop()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.examples)

    def __getitem__(
            self,
            idx: int,
    ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:

        def _tokens_and_segment_id(token_a: List[str], token_b: List[str] = None) -> Tuple[Any, List[int]]:
            tokens = ['[CLS]'] + token_a + ['[SEP]']  # See in 1-1. Section in /docs/Appendix.md
            token_type_ids = [0] * len(tokens)  # for more information of 138-145 lines
            if token_b:
                tokens += token_b + ['[SEP]']
                token_type_ids += [1] * (len(token_b) + 1)
            return tokens, token_type_ids

        text_a = self.examples[idx].text_a
        text_b = self.examples[idx].text_b
        label = self.examples[idx].label

            #   Convert texts into tokens
        tokens_a = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text_a)
        tokens_b = None
        if text_b:
            tokens_b = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text_b)
            # Modifies `tokens_a` and `tokens_b` in place so that the total
            # length is less than the specified length.
            # Account for [CLS], [SEP], [SEP] with '- 3'
            self._truncate_seq_pair(tokens_a, tokens_b, self.max_length)
        else:
            if len(tokens_a) > self.max_length - 2:
                tokens_a = tokens_a[:(self.max_length - 2)]

        tokens, token_type_ids = _tokens_and_segment_id(tokens_a, tokens_b)
        input_ids = self.tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
        label_ids = self.label_dict[label]

        # The mask has 1 for real tokens and 0 for padding tokens. Only real
        # tokens are attended to.
        attention_mask = [1] * len(input_ids)

        # Zero-pad up to the sequence length.
        padding = [0] * (self.max_length - len(input_ids))
        input_ids += padding
        attention_mask += padding
        token_type_ids += padding

        assert len(input_ids) == self.max_length
        assert len(attention_mask) == self.max_length
        assert len(token_type_ids) == self.max_length

        input_ids = torch.tensor(input_ids, dtype=torch.long)
        attention_mask = torch.tensor(attention_mask, dtype=torch.long)
        token_type_ids = torch.tensor(token_type_ids, dtype=torch.long)
        labels = torch.tensor(label_ids, dtype=torch.long)
        return input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, labels


class BertAccTestModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, num_classes: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained('klue/bert-base', num_labels=num_classes)
        self.model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('klue/bert-base', config=self.config)
        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('klue/bert-base')
        self.num_classes = num_classes

    def forward(self, init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids) -> SequenceClassifierOutput:
        outputs = self.model(init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids)
        return outputs

    def info(self, dictionary: dict) -> None:
        r"""
        Logging information from dictionary.
        Args:
            dictionary (dict): dictionary contains information.
        """
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            self.log(key, value, prog_bar=True, sync_dist=True)

    def training_step(self, batch: Tuple, batch_idx: int) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids = batch
        outputs = self.model(init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels=label_ids)
        top1_acc = F.accuracy(outputs.logits, label_ids)
        top1_f1 = F.f1_score(outputs.logits, label_ids, average='macro', num_classes=self.num_classes)
        loss = outputs.loss
        self.info({
            'train_loss': loss,
            'train_acc': top1_acc,
            'train_f1': top1_f1,
        })
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch: Tuple, batch_idx: int) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids = batch
        outputs = self.model(init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels=label_ids)
        top1_acc = F.accuracy(outputs.logits, label_ids)
        top1_f1 = F.f1_score(outputs.logits, label_ids, average='macro', num_classes=self.num_classes)
        loss = outputs.loss
        self.info({
            'val_loss': loss,
            'val_acc': top1_acc,
            'val_f1': top1_f1,
        })
        return loss

    def test_step(self, batch: Tuple, batch_idx: int) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids = batch
        outputs = self.model(init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels=label_ids)
        top1_acc = F.accuracy(outputs.logits, label_ids)
        top1_f1 = F.f1_score(outputs.logits, label_ids, average='macro', num_classes=self.num_classes)
        loss = outputs.loss
        self.info({
            'test_loss': loss,
            'test_acc': top1_acc,
            'test_f1': top1_f1,
        })
        return loss

    def predict_step(self, batch: Any, batch_idx: int, dataloader_idx: int = 0) -> Any:
        init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids = batch
        outputs = self(init_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids)
        return torch.argmax(outputs.logits)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        model = self.model
        no_decay = ["bias", "LayerNorm.weight"]
        optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters() if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters() if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": 0.0,
            },
        ]
        optim = torch.optim.AdamW(optimizer_grouped_parameters, lr=2e-5, eps=1e-8)
        scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
            optim,
            num_warmup_steps=500,
            num_training_steps=self.trainer.estimated_stepping_batches,
        )
        scheduler = {"scheduler": scheduler, "interval": "step", "frequency": 1}
        return [optim], [scheduler]


def main():
    root = '/'.join(os.getcwd().split('/'))
    print(root)
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('klue/bert-base', do_lower_case=False)

    train_examples, label_dict = add_examples(os.path.join(root, 'data/training_merged_1d.tsv'), text_index=2, label_index=7,  remove_top=True)
    eval_examples, _ = add_examples(os.path.join(root, 'data/validation.tsv'), text_index=2, label_index=7, label_dict=label_dict)
    test_examples, _ = add_examples(os.path.join(root, 'data/test.tsv'), text_index=2, label_index=7, label_dict=label_dict, remove_top=True)
    train_dataset = BertDataset(train_examples, tokenizer, max_length=256, label_dict=label_dict)
    eval_dataset = BertDataset(eval_examples, tokenizer, max_length=256, label_dict=label_dict)
    test_dataset = BertDataset(test_examples, tokenizer, max_length=256, label_dict=label_dict)

    print(len(train_dataset), len(eval_dataset), len(test_dataset))
    trn_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, num_workers=4, sampler=RandomSampler(train_dataset))
    eval_dataloader = DataLoader(eval_dataset, batch_size=64, num_workers=4, sampler=SequentialSampler(eval_dataset))
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=4, num_workers=4, sampler=SequentialSampler(test_dataset))
    inference_label_dict = {v: k for k, v in label_dict.items()}

    model = BertAccTestModel(num_classes= len(label_dict))
    checkpoint_callback = pl.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        save_last=True,
        save_weights_only=True,
        monitor='val_f1',
        mode='max',
        dirpath=os.path.join(root, 'weights'),
        filename='pytorch_model'
    )
    trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=4, max_epochs=10, accelerator='cuda', strategy='ddp', precision=32, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
    trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=trn_dataloader, val_dataloaders=eval_dataloader)
    trainer.test(model, test_dataloader)

    with open(os.path.join(root, 'weights', 'labels.dict'), 'w') as f:
        import json
        json.dump(inference_label_dict, f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of my code was related with multi-GPU. In multi-gpu environment, label_dict in add_examples created separately per GPU. for example,

```py
> Trainer(gpus=2)
> examples, labels = add_examples(*args)
> labels
> {'true': 1, 'false': 0}
> {'true': 0, 'false': 1}
```

The solution is that create label_dict file and load the label_dict file to add_example file.